# How to set option value equal option and put in into dropdown box?

Tags: angular

How to make option value equal option and display it ? 
I have a select:

```
<select>
<option *ngFor let year of year_Array ; let i=index; value="<option>">{{year}}</option></select>
```

and my TS:

```
getdata(year: string){

var date = new Date();
var y = date.getFullYear();

//let x:number = 3;

this.yearArray =[y,y+1,y+2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<option *ngFor let year of year_Array ; let i=index; [value]="year">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

Just need to wrap value in square brackets.